# Express.js: Reply with response from different route's request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get OAuth 2.0 working in my Express.js back end, but I'm struggling with letting the client know that the authorization was successful. Currently, my set up is like this:

1. Client at localhost:3000 makes a login request to the server at localhost:9000/login. Login request then opens the third party authorization URL in a new tab.
2. After authorizing, the new tab is redirected to localhost:9000/callback where the authorization code in the URL is used by the Express server at that route to obtain an access token.

My question now is, since my client originally made a request to localhost:9000/login, how do I respond to the login request from localhost:9000/callback, where the authorization is finalized?

Comment: Usually when you make such request you also add a return url. So the address would look like this localhost:9000/login?returnurl=localhost:3000 you need to save that url and use it in localhost:9000/callback

Comment: Not knowing the return URL isn't the problem. The problem is that the original request opens the authorization URL (for Spotify) which then redirects to a different route (/callback), so I have no way of using the response object in /callback to reply to the request made to /login.

Comment: Why do you want to reply to `/login` request? It's already finished due to redirect to Spotify's endpoint.

Comment: When you send the auth request you can add `state` param to the address and it will be returned. So in the login handler add the url to the state param which will be returned to the callback handler. https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#1-have-your-application-request-authorization-the-user-logs-in-and-authorizes-access